# What is the replacement of authorizeRequests() in spring security?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have the code below and i want to replace authorizeRequests because is deprecated

```
`@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain( HttpSecurity  httpSecurity) throws Exception{
    httpSecurity = httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(GET, "/api/user/**").hasAnyAuthotity("ROLE_USER")
            .and()
            .addFilter(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authManagerBuilder.getOrBuild()));
    return httpSecurity.build();
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeHttpRequestsCustomizer)` instead of `authorizeRequests()` and `authorizeHttpRequests()`. You can also refer to the Javadoc for the alternatives.

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain( HttpSecurity  httpSecurity) throws Exception{
    httpSecurity = httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeHttpRequests) ->
                            authorizeHttpRequests
                                    .antMatchers(GET, "/api/user/**").hasAnyAuthotity("ROLE_USER")
                    )
            .and()
            .addFilter(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authManagerBuilder.getOrBuild()));
    return httpSecurity.build();
}
```

References:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#authorizeRequests()

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#authorizeHttpRequests()

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#authorizeHttpRequests(org.springframework.security.config.Customizer)

Comment: authorizeHttpRequests() has since been deprecated.

Comment: You can refer to the java doc.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#authorizeHttpRequests(org.springframework.security.config.Customizer)


In the doc, You can see the examples. You need to move the antMatchers and hasAnyAuthotity inside the functional interface implementation.